# iPad orientation and xib files

Tags: ipad, file, xcode4, orientation, xib

I am using one xib file as my first screen in my iPad app.In that xib file I am using one image view in background and one button,if I click on that button then it will go to another page.My application supports both orientation.Now the problem is , suppose I click on that button and enter to the second page and then change the orientation of the device then go back to the main page, now in main page button's frame is changed. so I am not able to understand where to click to go to second page for second time.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a much better way that works independent of the nav controller. Right now, I have this working when embedded in a nav controller, and when NOT embedded (although I'm not using the nav controller right now, so there may be some bug I've not seen - e.g. the PUSH transition animation might go funny, or something)

Two NIBs, using Apple's naming convention. I suspect that in iOS 6 or 7, Apple might add this as a "feature". I'm using it in my apps and it works perfectly:

triggers on WILL rotate, not SHOULD rotate (waits until the rotate anim is about to start)
    uses the Apple naming convention for landscape/portrait files (Default.png is Default-landscape.png if you want Apple to auto-load a landscape version)
    reloads the new NIB
    which resets the self.view - this will AUTOMATICALLY update the display
    and then it calls viewDidLoad (Apple will NOT call this for you, if you manually reload a NIB)

(NB stackoverflow.com requires this sentence here - there's a bug in the code formatter)

```
 -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) )
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-landscape", NSStringFromClass([self class])] owner:self options:nil];

    [self viewDidLoad];

}
else
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSStringFromClass([self class])] owner:self options:nil];
     [self viewDidLoad];

}
}
```